# How can I solve this graph using the precise definition of limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

Use the given graph of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ to find a number $\delta$ such that

if $|x-4|<\delta$ then $|\sqrt{x}-2|<0.4$

[image: Precise Definition of a Limit Graph]

This precise definition of a limit has been giving me a lot of trouble, but so far I have the left value of x $f(x)=1.6$ $\sqrt{x}=1.6$ $x=2.56$, and the right value $f(x)=2.4$ $\sqrt{x}=2.4$ $x=5.76$

Now, I am stuck because I don't know what to do with this information. I think my main problem is that I don't understand this concept in general. I've been going through my textbook and the problems, I still don't get it. So far I've been able to do questions that already have all of the values of $x$ and $f(x)$ on the graph, but only because I have remembered what steps I'm supposed to take, not that I understand what I'm doing (not even the tiniest bit).

What are my next steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\delta=4-2.56$, so each element in the interval $]4-\delta,4+\delta[$ is taken, by $f$, into the $0.4$-neighbourhood of $2$.

Comment: Am I trying to find a number $\delta$ that is close to 4, so the limit is brought close to a $f(x)$ value that is less than 0.4? I apologize in advance is this question doesn't make much sense, this concept has been really hard for me to wrap my head around.

Comment: you are searching for $\delta$  to make a $\delta$-neighbourhood of $4$ such that for **each** point in it, they are carried $0.4$-near to $2$.

Answer (score 1):

$|\sqrt{x}- 2|< 0.4$ is the same as $-0.4< \sqrt{x}- 2< 0.4$

Since $\sqrt{x}$ is an increasing function, it is sufficient to look at the endpoints of the interval, $-0.4= \sqrt{x}- 2$ and $\sqrt{x}- 2|= 0.4$.

For $-0.4= \sqrt{x}- 2$ we have immediately $\sqrt{x}= -0.4+ 2= 1.6$.  Squaring both sides, $x= 2.56$. For $\sqrt{x}- 2= 0.4$, $\sqrt{x}= 2+ 0.4= 2.4$ and $x= 5.76$.

That is, $|\sqrt{x}- 4|< 0.4$ is true as long as $2.56< x< 5.76$.

$2.56= 4- 1.44$ and $5.76= 4+ 1.74$.  The smaller of those is 1.44 so $|x- 4|< 1.44$ will fit both.